# Generating Balance

Tags: php, mysql

I am generating a system that calculate the balance 
just like bank statement

```
Sr. date        Amount type     Balance
1.  1-2-2014     1     Debit    8
2.  1-2-2014     5     Debit    9       
3.  1-2-2014     5     Debit    14
4.  1-2-2014     15    Credit   19
5.  1-2-2014     3     Debit    4
--------------0 to 5------------------
Sr. date        Amount type     Balance
1.  1-1-2014     7    Credit    7
--------------0 to 5------------------

total 6 entries 
total debit=14
total credit=22
balance = 8
```

How can I manage balance with pagination. Every thing I can do but displaying balance in pagination.

> Note:If no entries  Initial Balance=0 Balance=(balance+credit)-debit

Comment: search for  "php pagination".... you can find tons of tutorials ....

Comment: oops! i have no issue with pagination issue is with managing balance

Comment: Run a query that selects all and then use https://www.datatables.net/

Comment: Why is this tagged `php`?